# How to use Windows Task Scheduler interactively on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

I've just made a new task that triggers an application from the command-line.
It seems that it's working (I check in log files), however I see no icon just as it used to be if I'd run the application in command-line window.

Besides, the application should create a PDF file and then open it within Acrobat Reader. The PDF file is created but nothing happens in regard to Acrobat Reader.

It seems that it's running in background somehow and ignore all features that should be displayed to screen. But I'd prefer to see this graphic features (on systray and Acrobat Reader). So my question is how to fix that?
I must say it's working well if the user uses the old-but-good "Scheduled Tasks" in Windows XP and Server 2003.

THANK YOU

Comment: Can you edit your question to include screenshots of your Task's properties? Also, is it set to run from an admin or limited account?

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem here:

- A scheduled Task will not interact with desktop, although the user is logged in

Diging on the Internet I have discovered how to enable desktop interaction for the Task Scheduler service, changing the following registry value from 20 to 120 (in hexadecimal)

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Schedule\Type

However this won't change things: the task will run, showing in the task manager, but won't interact with desktop. Any idea?

Comment: Similar Q at [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/458848/can-i-schedule-a-windows-task-to-run-in-an-interactive-desktop-session).

Answer (score 3):

It should work when the task is configured to "Run only when the user is logged on". No interaction with the desktop is possible when the task is configured otherwise. I think this behaviour started with Vista.